# What are the chances of getting 100 using mt_rand(1,100)?

Tags: php, math

I'm wondering what are the chances of getting 100 using mt_rand(1,100)?
Are the chances 1-100? does that mean I'll get atleast 100 once if i "roll" 100 times?

I've been wondering this for a while but I can't find any solution.
The reason why i wonder is because i'm trying to calculate how many times I have to roll in order to get 100 guaranteed.

```
<?php
$roll = mt_rand(1,100);
echo $roll;
?>
```

Regards Dennis

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP rate to chance for event to happen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833895/php-rate-to-chance-for-event-to-happen)

Comment: That's not what i'm asking for =/

Comment: In this case the answer can't be guaranteed. You can only claim that 100 will be found in the sequence with some probability.

Comment: Okay so there are no mathematically answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the chances 1-100? does that mean I'll get atleast 100 once if i "roll" 100 times?

No, thats not how random number generators work. Take an extreme example:

```
mt_rand(1, 2)
```

One would assume that over a *long enough* time frame that the number of 1s and the number of 2s would be the same. However, it is perfectly possible to get a sequence of 10 consecutive 1s. Just because its random, doesn't mean that a specific number *must* appear, if that were the case it would no longer be random.

> I'm trying to calculate how many times I have to roll in order to get 100 guaranteed.

Mathematically, there is no number where 100 is *guaranteed* to be in the sequence. If each roll is independent there is a `99/100` chance that it *won't* be 100.

For two rolls this is `(99/100)^2` or 98% likely. For 100 rolls its about 37% likely that you won't roll one `100` in that set. In fact, you need to roll in sets of 230 to have a less than 1% chance of having no 100s in the set.

Comment: I actually thought that in a long time frame the result would be nearly equal with your example. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

The probability of getting 100 is 1/100 by calling this function however there is no guarantee of getting 100 when you call it for the 100 times. You have to take a much bigger sample space. For example: If you call this function for 100,000,000 times, there are good chances that 100 will be found for 100,000 times.

This can be answered in a better way if you let us know about your use case in more detail.

Comment: I was actually just wondering if there was a guarantee let's say if you roll 2304 times you should get atleast 100 once because thats how mt_rand works but as it turns out that's not the case

Comment: There is no guarantee for that to happen, that's how probability and mt_rand both work. For your case, 2304 is not big enough.  There is no true random generator implementation, we can only get closer to the real randomness.

Comment: Can you please let us know why do you need this to be guaranteed in real world scenario?

Comment: I'm playing much casino online and I have been wondering what the chances really are if it's 1 to 100 if you were using mt_rand for instance.

Comment: The probability works well with the bigger sample space, so if the probability  of winning a roulette spin is 1/36 if you bet on a number, the player may not win even once after playing 100 games, but if you see this number for all the bets that were made in a single day for all the players, players would have won at least once in every 36 spins. So, on bigger sample space it is true. I have worked in real money casino gaming for 5 years so I know it well ;) , which game are you playing btw?

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer. Don't laugh but I usually play Spider Man Attack and Premium European Roulette on ladbrokes (online) but i dont understand the 1% chance of jackpot thing but I'm starting to

Comment: Great, generally chances of winning a jackpot is much less than 1%, (it depends on a lot of other things like amount of jackpot, type of game, any other constraints though). But if it is indeed 1%, it means, if house receives 100 bets, in long run, 1 player will win the jackpot. But as you would have guessed, there is no pattern on who and when, this ratio is valid only on a long run, big sample space, without any pattern.

Answer (score 0):

getting 1 out of 100 rolls is just a statistical way of explaining it. though there is **1%**(means 1 out of 100), it doesn't mean you really will get one 1 out of 100 rolls. it's a matter of chances.

Comment: Yeah i'm starting to understand that hehe. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[`mt_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) uses the Mersenne Twister to generate pseudo random numbers, that are said to be [uniform distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29). So if, you set min and max values, it should be (most likely) also uniform distributed.

So: you can only talk about the propability to get a number in the given range and also about an expected number of trys until you get a specific number or all numbers in range.

This means: No guarantees for a given number number to get a specific number at least once.

Comment: I see. but in theory (mt_rand(0, 1) === 0) is 50% chance?

Comment: So then (mt_rand(0, 100) === 0) would be 1% chance?

Comment: kind of. (0 to 100 are 101 elements) the expected number of trys is 100, but you can't be sure that you really get the nubmer.

Comment: Ok, I dont get it tho. If 0,100 is 101 elements, how can it be 1%? does that mean (mt_rand(0, 2) === 0) is 25% chance??

Comment: 0,1 is 2 elements, 0,100 is 101 elements, so it is slightly less than 1%. I thought you mean 0,99 so it is100 elements range and the numbers are nicer to write.